# Problema ao extrair arquivo zip - ZipFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo-zip, python-requests

Refazendo a pergunta na tentativa de deixa-la mais clara.

Um webhook chama minha API enviando uma requisição POST.
No body da requisição contem a url de um arquivo ZIP.

Utilizando a biblioteca requests, realizo um GET na url do arquivo.
Eu preciso extrair este alguns arquivos deste zip e realizar uma série de processos.
O problema é que ao tentar extrair o arquivo me deparo com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xa2' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Código da requisição e tentativa de extrair o arquivo:

```py
import io
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get(url)

with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
    thezip.extractall()
```

Quando dou um print na lista de nomes do arquivo:

```py
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
    print(thezip.namelist())
```

```
['Nao_Consistido/', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio de Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\x86o - Limite Inferior - LI.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio de Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\x86o - Limite Superior - LS.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio_de_Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\xa4es_PMO_de_DEZEMBRO_2019-preliminar.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_LI.prv', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_LS.prv', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_VE.prv']
```

Já defini a variável de ambiente PYTHONIOENCODING para utf-8 e não funcionou. 
EDIT:
Após alguns testes percebi que o problema ocorre apenas no servidor(sistema linux), localmente no Windows 10 não ocorre.

Comment: Gustavo, seria melhor você [edit] sua pergunta anterior do que criar uma nova, uma pergunta só é fechada até que seu autor a melhore.. Não é uma situação definitiva...

Comment: Eu fiz essa edição mas pergunta permaneceu fechada, isso ocorre automaticamente?

Comment: Não, existe uma votação para a reabertura. A [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) explica melhor o funcionamento. O que você pode fazer é comentar lá e pedir _feedback_ para a comunidade... assim você saberá o que melhorar na pergunta.

Comment: ok obrigado, vou fazer